# Regex, excluding super-pattern

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I want to find all instances of comments starting with `//`, but I want to exclude all URLs that look like `http://`.

How can I do this using a regex?

```
((?!http:)//).*\n // This does not work as URLs are still matched.
```

Comment: I think you can use `(?<!:)//.*`. What is your regex flavor?

Comment: @stribizhev Yes that appears to work. Is that a negative look-behind?

Comment: Sublime text 3 - whatever flavor that is...

Comment: Yes, it is a negative lookbehind. It is PCRE if you are using S&R, and Oniguruma if you create a plugin.

Comment: I do not know how to correctly match the comments in `function foo () { var s = "Some // weird\" string?"; } // my "comment"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?!...)` is a negative look**ahead** (*if not followed by*); you need a negative look**behind** (*if not preceded by*): `(?<!...)`.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to find all instances of comments ***starting*** with `//`

Why can't you just use `^//` or am I missing something? You can use `^\s+//` to account for any whitespace that you might encounter.

Okay. I get what you're saying, but in that case, you could do it like this:

```
(^|[^:]|\s+)(\/\/.*)
```

In the above, you're simply making sure that `//` is not preceded by `:`. As simple as it gets. Also make sure that you'd replace including the first group as well to prevent any loss of data.

Like: `$1replacement_term_here`

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/bZ9dA9/3).

Comment: Because your regex fails to match `function foo () {} // my comment` My original question may have been unclear.

Comment: This regex will match the preceding char(s) as well (i.e. `:` or `\s`). That is, if you replace the matches by an empty string in `foo() {}// bar`, you'll get `foo() {`: the last `}` will be removed as well. This is why I believe a lookbehind better suits OP's needs.

Comment: @sp00m well, he could well replace with `$1"something here"` can't he?

Comment: @AmitJoki Of course, but it looks more *hacky* than replacing by `"something here"` ;) Especially when lookarounds exist.

Comment: @sp00m well yeah :D But you know I'm arguing for the sake of it and also partly due to the fact that I can't now just edit to include lookarounds. You know this answer's initial version was completely different.